# Newb question, about LLDP for inventory

Tags: lldp, switchport

New (to enterprise networking) guy--

My org is facing room re-numbering of a 5 building, multi floor campus, wherein all nodes (PCs, printers, A/V) will need to be renamed. 
Wondering if, after the renaming, would there a way to update port aliases, via LLDP, OFDP, whatever, to avoid manually updating new names. (Seems like port aliases shouldn't be handled manually in any case...)

Comment: LLDP is essentially "read only" so you can't use it to change things.

Comment: There are network management tools to do that type of thing.

Comment: RT, I got you, but endpoint devices (ex. phones) can advertise their info. I just thought it would be ideal to have switches read the advertised names of those endpoints and use as their aliases.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would need some form of script to do this in a sane manner - it would need to log into the switch, check the LLDP neighbor and update the port description.

I question the point of this though, since you have this information in LLDP already, and it is automatically updated when someone re-patches their device, unlike the script method which would have to be re-run every time a port changes state (in case people are moving stuff).

LLDP also wouldn't work for most hosts, without installing 3rd-party agents, but APs and Phones (and some printers) are able to self-report out of the box.

You don't mention your switch vendor, but some support NetBIOS snooping, whereby you can discover the SMB Network Name of connected devices automatically as well.

Comment: These are Extreme switches... I figured I would have to do something on the endpoints, agent-wise.